# How to track transactions on ethereum using node application and fire a function on complete transaction

Tags: blockchain, go-ethereum

I am trying to run a function if I got the ether on my wallet.
I am using geth and nodejs. Can someone suggest me how to do that.

Comment: geth nodes have something called RPC which allows you to communicate to them while they're running. Google that and you'll probably find something in the docs

Comment: @jeanluc, I know about RPC and communication with it, but I am not able to find the way to track each incoming transaction on particular public address. Do you have any particular way to do that?.